# Selected option is not scrolled into view in mat-select

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7

I'm having an issue with mat-select in my Angular 7 App.The mat-select in question has a lot of options and therefore a scroll bar is displayed, as it should be.
When I select an option in the mat-select, and the close it. On re-opening it, the option is selected but it is not auto-scrolled into view. The drop-down re-opens from the first item always. But I want the dropdown to auto-scroll to the selected option. Isn't this default behaviour of mat-select?

Ill explain it with screen shots:

I first select a value:

[image]

and then close the drop down. And then on reopening, the list starts from first option.

[image]

[image]

But I want the drop down to auto-scrollto selected option.

The dropdown code is as follows:

```
    <mat-select class="selectFont" [disableOptionCentering]='true' disableRipple panelClass="panel- 
    css-pat-reg-title-reg-page"[(ngModel)]="patient.title" name="title" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let title of title" [value]="title.display">
                    {{title.display}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Any help in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: try to find your solution here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3419

Comment: @AntonSkybun looked into it...but it seems the usecase is a bit different

Comment: Share a stackblitz demo or more complete code. The problem is most likely that the selected option's value is not being persisted to the select's model.